# Matching words, NOT characters with NPP

Tags: regex, notepad++

i have some ASCII files here whose lines i would like to prefix with the date but only those NOT starting with "DA" or "DE".

```
DEPARTAMENTO DE FILOSOFIA
DATA    LOCAL   HORÁRIO DISCIPLINA  TURMA   PROF(A) OCORRÊNCIA  ASSISTENTE
LAB-02  20:20-21:10 INF007  ?   GRINALDO    AD  FERREIRA
DEPARTAMENTO DE HISTÓRIA
DATA    LOCAL   HORÁRIO DISCIPLINA  TURMA   PROF(A) OCORRÊNCIA  ASSISTENTE
D-202   15:20-17:00 HISTORIA    2831    MICHELE AD  AILTON
DEPARTAMENTO DE LINGUAS ESTRANGEIRAS
DATA    LOCAL   HORÁRIO DISCIPLINA  TURMA   PROF(A) OCORRÊNCIA  ASSISTENTE
D-106   18:40-20:20 INGLES  13752   DEISE   FT+AD   AILTON
```

I use search & replace, this "^(.[^AE].*)$" by "01/01/2017\t\1" (gets any line starting by anything folowed by A or E til thr EOL and replaces for DATE tabulation LINE). It produces:

```
DEPARTAMENTO DE FILOSOFIA
DATA    LOCAL   HORÁRIO DISCIPLINA  TURMA   PROF(A) OCORRÊNCIA  ASSISTENTE
LAB-02  20:20-21:10 INF007  ?   GRINALDO    AD  FERREIRA
DEPARTAMENTO DE HISTÓRIA
DATA    LOCAL   HORÁRIO DISCIPLINA  TURMA   PROF(A) OCORRÊNCIA  ASSISTENTE
01/01/2017  D-202   15:20-17:00 HISTORIA    2831    MICHELE AD  AILTON
DEPARTAMENTO DE LINGUAS ESTRANGEIRAS
DATA    LOCAL   HORÁRIO DISCIPLINA  TURMA   PROF(A) OCORRÊNCIA  ASSISTENTE
01/01/2017  D-106   18:40-20:20 INGLES  13752   DEISE   FT+AD   AILTON
```

But doesn't capture "LAB.*". How can i do it so it realy capture lines not starting by "DE" or "DA" but yes for "D-"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `^(.[^AE].*)$` regex matches a line that starts with any char other than line break chars, then has any char (even a newline!) other than `A` and `E`, and then may have any 0+  chars other than line break chars.

Use the following expression:

Find what: `^(?!D[AE]).*` 
Replace with: `01/01/2017\t$0`

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a line...
- `(?!D[AE])` - that is not followed with `D`, and then `A` or `E`
- `.*` - matches all the rest of the line that is referred with the `$0` backreference in the replacement pattern.

[image]